# Using ng-repeat. Filter out repeated value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hoping someone might be able to provide some help for this. I even had trouble trying to write up a decent title for this problem.

I currently have an array that contains a name and score. Sometimes the array will contain values from the same name, but with a different score.

For example:

```
$scope.name = [{
        'first': 'jim',
            'score': 10
    }, {
        'first': 'frank',
            'score': 90,
    }, {
        'first': 'jim',
            'score': 20
    }]
```

You can see this in my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6yghdfg2/1/

```
<li ng-repeat="eachname in filteredName = (name) | orderBy:'first'">
```

I know how to display and sort the data so the output would be:

```
frank 
90
jim 
10
jim 
20
```

However, I am wondering if there is anyway to only display each name once, so the output would be:

```
frank 
90
jim 
10
20
```

Would ng-repeat be used in this situation? I keep thinking I have to make some type of filter or try to do some ng-show. Really not sure.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!
T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="eachname in filteredName = (name | orderBy:'first')">
            <span ng-show="filteredName[$index-1].first != filteredName[$index].first">
                {{eachname.first}} <br>
            </span>
            {{eachname.score}}
        </li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p1t9yac9/